# CA1063 Warning and override Dispose Confusion--Unsure if I should Suppress

Tags: c#

I have project that is running just fine. However I am getting a CA1063 error and before I suppress I want to see if I am implement Dispose incorrectly.

It starts with an interface I have defined:

```
public interface IAttributeRepository
{
    IDataTransaction BeginTransaction();

    Task<IQueryable<AttributeValue>> GetAttributeValues(int parentId);

...etc....

}
```

Notice that anything implementing this interface must also implement IDataTransaction so here that is:

```
public interface IDataTransaction : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
    void RollBack();
}
```

Now I have defined two types of SQL interactions in my repository layer. Simple one and then those that should be wrapped in a transaction.

The transaction one is what we care about and it is defined as a private class member var as such:

```
private DBTransaction _dbTransaction;
```

The class DBTransaction looks like this:
(DbTransaction is a Msoft object in System.Data.Entity)

```
public class DBTransaction : IDataTransaction
{
    DbContextTransaction _dbcontextTrans;

    public DBTransaction(DbContextTransaction dbcontexttrans)
    { _dbcontextTrans = dbcontexttrans; }

    public void Commit()
    { _dbcontextTrans.Commit(); }

    public void RollBack()
    { _dbcontextTrans.Rollback(); }

    public void Dispose()
    { _dbcontextTrans.Dispose(); }
}
```

Finally in a repository class it would be used like this:

```
public class AttributeRepository : IAttributeRepository
{
   public IDataTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        var trans = _DataContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        _dbTransaction = new DBTransaction(trans);
        return _dbTransaction;            
    }


    public async Task<IQueryable<Data.Attribute>> GetAttribute_with_AttributeValues(int id)
    {
        using (var trans = this.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //execute sql code you want wrapped in a transaction

            //rollback, commit etc based upon result
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned the code executes correctly I'm just not sure I understand why code analysis is telling me my dispose needs correcting and before I just suppress it I want to verify with those far more knowledgeable than I.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Useful info here: [Framework Design Guidelines - Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

This is the pattern I would follow when implementing `IDisposable` on the `DBTransaction` class:

```
public class DBTransaction : IDataTransaction
{
    ....
    ~DBTransaction() {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(_disposed) return;            
        try
        {
            // DISPOSE OF UN-MANAGED RESOURCES HERE
            if(disposing)
            {
                //  Dispose objects here
                _dbcontextTrans.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

If you are deriving from a base class that implements `IDisposable` and has a `virtual` dispose method, then I would do this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(_disposed)
        return;
    try
    {
        // DISPOSE OF UN-MANAGED RESOURCES HERE
        if(disposing)
        {
            //  Dispose objects here           
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _disposed = true;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

This is very similar to the normal `Dispose(bool disposing)`, but in the `finally` block I call `base.Dispose(disposing)`.

EDIT #1: 
Updated to take into account suggestion from @juharr.